# Ansible - compare values from two different dictionaries and output when there is a match

Tags: dictionary, ansible, compare, jinja2

I have two Ansible dictionaries

```
    "small_d": {
        "cluster-c8836": [
            "aaaa-111",
            "bbbb-222",
            "cccc-222"
        ]
    }
```

and

```
    "big_d": {
        "2cc5b2fbe6c6": [
            "dddd-asda",
            "aaaa-111",
            "ddd-2411",
            "bbbb-222",
            "dddd-76543",
            "cccc-222",
            "dddd-66666"
        ],
        "0a722267a5bd": [
            "dddd-2468"
        ]
    }
```

I want to loop through the values of small_d to see if the same value exists in big_d.
If it does, i'd like to output the relevant key from big_d and a list of the matching values
e.g.

```
"2cc5b2fbe6c6": ["aaaa-111", "bbbb-222", "cccc-222"]
```

I'm trying this with a Jinja2 template

```
- name: try Jinja2 filtering
  set_fact:
    worth_a_try: |
      {% for cluster_id, node_ids in small_d.items() %}
      {% for node_id in node_ids %}
      {% for group_id, member_ids in big_d.items() %}
      {% if node_id in member_ids %}
        - {{group_id}}:
            {{node_id}}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
- debug: var=worth_a_try
```

The output that i'm getting is

```
    worth_a_try|from_yaml": [
        {
            "2cc5b2fbe6c6": "aaaa-111"
        },
        {
            "2cc5b2fbe6c6": "bbbb-222"
        },
        {
            "2cc5b2fbe6c6": "cccc-222"
        }
```

How best can I clean up this output ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to stick with your Jinja block, here is one implementation. Basically create a dictionary with keys all the keys of big_d dictionary and values initialized as a list. Each time the condition is met, append to the group_id's value the node_id. At the end a loop to print the yaml formatted variable.

Jinja task:

```
  - name: try Jinja2 filtering
    set_fact:
      worth_a_try: |
        {% set cluster_dict = {} %}
        {% for group_id in big_d.keys() %}
        {% set _ = cluster_dict.update({group_id: []}) %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for cluster_id, node_ids in small_d.items() %}
        {% for node_id in node_ids %}
        {% for group_id, member_ids in big_d.items() %}
        {% if node_id in member_ids %}
        {% set _ = cluster_dict.update({group_id: cluster_dict[group_id] + [node_id]}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for key, value in cluster_dict.items() %}
        {% if value != [] %}
        - {{ key}}:
        {% for entry in value %}
          - {{ entry }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

  - debug:
      var: worth_a_try|from_yaml
```

Prints:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "worth_a_try|from_yaml": [
        {
            "2cc5b2fbe6c6": [
                "aaaa-111",
                "bbbb-222",
                "cccc-222"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```